# Play 2.4 cacheApi (EhCache) get cached value from disk after activator reload

Tags: playframework, ehcache

I have a problem with EhCache in Play 2.4, when I add object to cache (disk persistent) and try to read everything is fine. But when I cause play reload by changing something in configuration or code. Value cannot be read.

Link for github project https://github.com/aswarcewicz/cache-test

Controller code:

```
class CacheController @Inject()(cacheApi: CacheApi) extends Controller {
  implicit val vFormat = Json.format[ValueObject]
  implicit val rFormat = Json.format[Response]

  val key = "key"
  val valueToTest = ValueObject("test1", "test2")


  def value(): Action[AnyContent] = Action.async {
    Future {
      val withCast = cacheApi.get[ValueObject](key)
      val withoutCast = cacheApi.get(key).toString

      Ok(Json.toJson(Response(withCast, withoutCast)))
    }
  }

  def setValue(): Action[AnyContent] = Action.async {
    Future {
      cacheApi.set(key, valueToTest)

      Ok("value set")
    }
  }
}

// value object to store in cache
case class ValueObject(field1: String, field2: String)

// object for response
case class Response(withCast: Option[ValueObject], withoutCast: String)
```

Step to reproduce:
 1. Add something to cache by open http://localhost:9000/set
 2. Get previous object from cache by open http://localhost:9000/get result is => {"withCast":{"field1":"test1","field2":"test2"},"withoutCast":"Some(ValueObject(test1,test2))"}
 3. change something in code or configuration to cause play reload
 4. open again http://localhost:9000/get to read cached object from disk, result is => {"withoutCast":"Some(ValueObject(test1,test2))"}

Comment: What does your Ehcache configuration look like?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache>
<diskStore path="./target"/>
<defaultCache
diskPersistent="true"
maxEntriesLocalHeap="1000"
/>
</ehcache>

Comment: Shouldn't your configuration have a persistence element, like in http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/configuration/fast-restart.html?

Comment: I think that's the expected behaviour when you restart the application.